# C++ static compilation of function with a variable number or arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I found myself writing code like this:

```
template <class T>
inline bool allequal(T a,T b,T c) {return a==b&&a==c;}
template <class T>
inline bool allequal(T a,T b,T c,T d) {return a==b&&a==c&&a==d;}
template <class T>
inline bool allequal(T a,T b,T c,T d,T e) {return a==b&&a==c&&a==d&&a==e;}
```

I was wondering if there is an automated way of doing that, without using vectors or variadic arguments, as speed is important in this context.

Comment: What about variadic templates ? Are you using C++11 ?

Comment: @Ninetainedo Yes I am using C++11. How would that look like? Can you propose an example?

Comment: Why do you think variadic templates slow down code ?

Comment: @Jagannath, He is not talking about variadic templates but variadic arguments using `va_arg`, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T >
inline bool allequal( const T& v )
{
  return true;
}

template< typename T, typename U, typename... Ts >
inline bool allequal( const T& v, const U& v1, const Ts&... Vs)
{
  return (v == v1) && allequal( v1, Vs... );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << allequal(1, 1, 1, 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << allequal(1, 1, 2, 2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

AFAIK there is a proposal for C++17 to include custom expansion of variadic templates with operators that could avoid this kind of recursion and this ugly (IMO) termination with `return true` for one argument.

Note: this could possibly not be inlined for many arguments.

Comment: Variadic arguments, not templates. He's talking about `va_args`

Comment: This will evaluate to true for `(1, 1, 2, 2)` and fail to compile for `(1, 2, 3)`. Did you mean `allequal(v1, Vs...)` (and a recursion stopper with one argument)?

Comment: You could combine with `all_same` to `return false;` if types are differents.

Comment: In C++17 you could use `((v == Vs) && ...)` (and omit `v1`); more details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). clang 3.6 accepts it with `std=c++1z`; I'm not sure about gcc 5 (4.9 does not).

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool allequal(T a, Args... rest)
{
    std::initializer_list<T> values = {a, rest...};
    return std::adjacent_find(begin(values), end(values), std::not_equal_to<T>()) == end(values);
}
```

[Working demo](https://ideone.com/IwoAmp)

Comment: This is perfect answer. Can you avoid copy by value?

Comment: I like the logic behind it. But don't you think that this will be compiled with some sort of for loop, and therefore be less efficient than the other solutions?

Comment: I'd have to profile it to see. Both other answers are recursive, this method is iterative. Note that it will short-circuit, so as soon as it finds two elements with `not_equal_to`, it will bail early without iterating the through the remaining elements. But so will the recursive methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename First, typename Second>
bool AllOf(First a, Second b)
{
    return a == b;
}

template<typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest>
bool AllOf(First a, Second b, Rest... r)
{
    return  a == b && AllOf(b, r...);
}


std::cout << AllOf(1, 1,1,1) << "\n";
std::cout << AllOf(1, 1,2) << "\n";
std::cout << AllOf(1,2) << "\n";
std::cout << AllOf(1,1) << "\n";
```